# MDI container and Form's border in vb6?

Tags: forms, vb6, mdi

[image: MDI Form problem]

Attached is an image of MDI container and form.
So I have an mdi container and multiple child forms. The in the Image you can see the first child form called "Main Menu". I'm trying to get rid of the borders of teh forms, so only the mdi container border can be seen. I looked at the properties and changed BORDERSTYLE = NONE and WINDOWSTATE = NORMAL. So this takes the borders off. The first time it opens in the MDI container, the form looks good. The problem arises when I come back to the MAIN MENU form, because each time I do, the forms keep moving towoards the right corner, which is very odd? Please see the image and help a brother out.

Answer (score 0):

You're unloading and reloading your child form, and that's the expected (default) behavior.

In your child form load event, set the child form's top and left properties to zero.

In that load event, you might also want to set the child form's width and height properties to the MDI parent form's ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight properties.  This will size the child form to take up the MDI parent form's available display area.